# Using L'Hospital rule, how do we tell that $\int_0^x \sin^{-1} (t^2) dt =0$?

Tags: limits

> Find the limit, $\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{\int_0^x \sin^{-1} t^2 dt}{\sin(x^2)}$

This came out in my exam and unknowingly, I did the L'Hospital rule and got it correct, but I do not understand how $\int_0^x \sin^{-1} t^2 dt = 0$ ?

The denominator is $0$ as $\sin (0) =0$ and I used LH rule because it is in the form of $\frac{0}{0}$

Using L-H rule on the numerator, it involves the first fundamental theroem of calculus

$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x \sin^{-1} t^2 dt = \sin^{-1} x^2$ and I would know how to carry on. So, how do I determine that $\int_0^x \sin^{-1} t^2 dt = 0$ ?

Comment: Why do you want to "determine that $\int_0^x \sin^{-1} t^2 dt = 0$" (whatever that means)? You solved the exercise without this, didn't you?

Comment: The numerator tends to $0$ because $\sin^{-1}$ is bounded.

Comment: Or simply by continuity of $x\mapsto\int_0^x\dots$ (which is even differentiable, as you showed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you plug in $0$ for the limit you’re plugging in $0$ for $x$ not $t$.

$$\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{\int_0^x \sin^{-1} t^2 dt}{\sin(x^2)}$$ basically means $$\frac{\int_0^0\sin^{-1} t^2 dt}{\sin(0^2)}=0/0$$

Which is obvious since an integral with the same bounds will always equal $0$. Because it’s $0/0$ then you’d apply le hospital rule and so on the solve the limit.

This means that $\int_0^x \sin^{-1} t^2 dt\neq 0$, but $\int_0^0\sin^{-1} t^2 dt=0$

Hopefully this clears up some misunderstanding.

As a side note the actual integral can be expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions as  shown here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=integrate+arcsin%28x%5E2%29+from+0+to+x

Answer (score 1):

Let $N(x):=\int_0^x \sin^{-1} (t^2)\,\mathrm dt.$

As you showed, $N$ is differentiable. Hence it is continuous, so that
$$\lim_{x\to0}N(x)=N(0)=0,$$
which is the only thing you missed to apply L'Hôpital's rule.